# Mips Assembly Finding the maximum value of a user-created array

Tags: arrays, integer, max, mips

I am a couple of weeks into my CS-250 Computer Organization and Architecture class and we are currently studying the MIPS Assembly language. I am trying to take a user inputted array and find the maximum number in that array. I do not quite understand how to use the slt keyword in this context, as this is what our professor would like us to do.

Here is my current code. If you have any suggestions I am super open to the ideas. The only blank spot I currently have is the function for finding the maximum value of the array.

```
.globl main

.data
array: .space 2000
prompt: .asciiz "Enter the number of integers you would like to input: "
input: .asciiz "Enter an intger: "
Max: .asciiz "Maxiumum Value is: "

.text

main:
    #Loading array into $t5
    la $t5, array

    li $s0, 0

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $s1, $v0

Loop: 
    #Asking the user for input
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, input
    syscall

    #Storing user input in array address in $t5
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    sw $v0, 0($t5)

    #Counting iterations for the loop as well as the array address
    addi $s0, $s0, 1
    addi $t5, $t5, 4

    #Loop Exit
    beq $s0, $s1, Maximum
    j Loop

 Maximum: 


 Exit: 
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: I assume you already have _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_. If not, the first thing you should do is download it.

The description for `SLT rd,rs,rt` is _"Compare the contents of GPR rs and GPR rt as signed integers and record the Boolean result of the comparison in
GPR rd. If GPR rs is less than GPR rt, the result is 1 (true); otherwise, it is 0 (false)"_. As you can imagine, one can combine `SLT` with a `BEQ` or `BNE` to create an `if (rs < rt)` or `if (rs >= rt)`. There's also an `SLTU` if you want to treat the inputs as unsigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
.globl main

.data
array: .space 2000
prompt: .asciiz "Enter the number of integers you would like to input: "
input: .asciiz "Enter an intger: "
Max: .asciiz "Maxiumum Value is: "

.text
main:
    #Loading array into $t5
    la $t5, array

    li $s0, 0

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $s1, $v0

Loop: 
    #Asking the user for input
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, input
    syscall

    #Storing user input in array address in $t5
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    sw $v0, 0($t5)

    #Counting iterations for the loop as well as the array address
    addi $s0, $s0, 1
    addi $t5, $t5, 4

    #Loop Exit
    beq $s0, $s1, Maximum
    j Loop

Maximum:
    la $t5, array # load the array start address
    lw $t2, 0($t5) # max = first element
    li $s0, 0 # i = 0

Max_loop:
    lw $t3, 0($t5) # temp = actual array element
    slt $t4, $t2, $t3 # max < temp ?
    bne $t4, 1, Else # jump to else branch if it condition is false
    move $t2, $t3 # condition was true let max = temp

Else:
    addi $s0, $s0, 1 # i++
    addi $t5, $t5, 4 # array += 4
    beq $s0, $s1, Exit # i < num
    j Max_loop

Exit: 
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Everything seems to work correctly with MARS 4.5 MIPS simulator. The result is in `$t2` on exit. You could easily add the code to print its value if you want to.

The `slt $t1, $t2, $t3` will bascially do this in C like code:

```
if ($t2 < $t3)
  $t1 = 1
else
  $t1 = 0
```

So based on it you could achieve conditional branching using it result.

Note that the code I provided not necessary optimal and could be problematic if the user input less than `1`, but this should be checked in the input stage anyway.